# What is the source to forbid Toldos תולדות?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, torts-damages, hermeneutics

There are times that Torah gives specific "examples" of what is forbidden (e.g. 39 melachos given via a reference to the actions done in the משכן or through other means; Or The Torah specifies 4 cases of damages for which one is liable.

However, what is the source that tells us that these are not meant only as specific issurim, but rather "אבות"  e.g. avos melachos (Shabbos Mishnah 7:2) or "avos nezikin" (Bava Kamma 1:1) under which other (similar) actions can be included.  i.e. meant not as specific prohibitions only forbidding what it says (e.g. separating grain from the husk) but rather to be a general description from which תולדות come out from (e.g. to say bruising someone, so that the blood is no separated from its location is also forbidden with the same severity).
It doesn't seem to be that we learn these out via מה מצינו, or that they are דרשות learned out via the י"ג מדות שהתורה נדרשת בהם.  If so, where does this license come from?
The Gemara is Shabbos 70b learns הנה אבות מהנה תולדות however it doesn't seem to be learning out that this is the source of the concept/ability to make Toldos, but rather how the halachos of Toldos work (that they are included - i.e. "from" the Av and not viewed as separately in regards to שגגות והעלמות).
And even if it would be a source, it would still leave the question of where the source is for nezikin.  The Gemara seems to only say מדתני אבות מכלל דאיכא תולדות in other words the language the that Tanna used implies that there are more- and thus what are they.  But there doesn't seem to be any "מנלן" to find how the Tanna was able to include more in what the Torah stated.

And the other question (aside from the source), is whether it's limited (e.g. to Shabbos, Nezikin) and if so, why would it be limited to only those cases.  Or, are all issurim in the Torah meant in the same manner, such that in theory any action that entails the same essence is included?

Comment: http://asif.co.il/?wpfb_dl=6696

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106882/what-are-the-biblical-sources-for-rabbinic-authority/106968?r=SearchResults#106968

Comment: @Gershon:  Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: To summarize (@Gershon's link) - he says that (a) מהר"י כ"ץ (brought in the שיטה מקובצת ב"ק ב ע"א) says that "later" in Bava Kamma the Gemara learns it from סברא, and he implies that this סברא applies also to Shabbos.  (b) Tos' learn it from the derash הנה מהנה (brought in Shabbos 70b)

Comment: Q - Does anyone know which Gemara מהר"י כ"ץ is referring to (in Bava Kamma) that learns it from סברא?

Comment: Q - The Tos' referenced (Q Gershon)  states that of course the fact that plucking feathers is חייב on Shabbos (as a תולדה of shearing) has no application in regards to the prohibition against shearing a bechor.  (Implying that the concept of תולדה doesn't exist re: the issur of לא תגוז of a bechor, and presumably anywhere else).  Q- Tos don't state that Shabbos is different because of the דרשה of הנה - אבות, מהנה - תולדות (he seems to assume that).  However, since it's unique to Shabbos- what's the source for תולדות  for נזיקין?

Comment: @Sochacz - thanks for the link, and I skimmed through it, and found it useful in general, but didn't see what you intended to direct me to in regard to תולדות.

Comment: Chiam- Thank you. Your correct, looking at your question again, the link did not answer it. I apologize. I thought you asked a simpler question of how we know the halacha of תולדות in General. To which I wanted to say the Rabbanim taught it.

Comment: @Sochacz - no apology needed, I gained other info and mareeh mekomos looking through it.