# How to interpret statements of Rabbonim on the nature of reality

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, daas-torah, emunat-chachamim

I know that some people tend to take more or less everything that a Rav says as the absolute truth, but throughout the ages, different Rabbonim have expressed a variety of opinions, which can, in many cases, completely contradict each other.

Even when they don't, I tend to think that when writing on the nature of reality (physical, spiritual or otherwise), a large part of what Rabbonim have written was intended to be taken as "this is my belief (or even theory) of how things work", and not "this is the only objective truth".  I tend to assume that I should have great respect for the authors of these works, and assume that they are far greater than I ever will be, and perhaps some of it is mesorah which has been passed down the generations from a novi, but that I don't necessarily need to believe that everything that they have written is 100% objectively correct, and I also tend to think that in some cases, we have access to information that they may not have had which may shed more light on a specific matter.

Is this approach correct or am I doing something wrong in some way?  Does this come down to hashkafa that eg. it is acceptable in Modern Orthodoxy, but not amongst Charedim?  Are there any sources which discuss this?

Comment: Related questions: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11617/31534 (and its duplicate). Also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106882/31534. This question might need more focus, as there might be some things that will be universally accepted as "theory" and some where there might be a disagreement. I think I get the gist of it, but might help to get some concrete examples

Comment: Volume one: https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Jewish-Thought-1/dp/0940118491/ref=sr_1_1?crid=ACG25LOZ6QBR&keywords=The+Handbook+of+Jewish+Thought&qid=1701896609&sprefix=the+handbook+of+jewish+thought%2Caps%2C82&sr=8-1

Comment: Volume two: https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Jewish-Thought-2/dp/0940118793/ref=sr_1_2?crid=ACG25LOZ6QBR&keywords=The+Handbook+of+Jewish+Thought&qid=1701896609&sprefix=the+handbook+of+jewish+thought%2Caps%2C82&sr=8-2

Comment: My suggestion to you, since you have already expressed a respect and interest in the writings of Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, is that you acquire and read the 2 volume, "The Handbook of Jewish Thought" written by him. It will answer concisely many of the things you are asking here. And like he always did, with copious footnotes to original traditional sources for every statement.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150175/discussion-on-question-by-moses-supposes-how-to-interpret-statements-of-rabbonim); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: More related questions: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/are-gedolei-yisroel-fallible https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/how-can-i-know-a-rav-has-daas-torah